# Getting "No Repository Found" error in Eclipse (Ganymede) while trying to install google plugins (GWT)

Tags: eclipse, gwt, installation

I'm trying to install the Google Web Toolkit for Eclipse (Ganymede), and I'm getting the following error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.emf.common/osgi.bundle/2.4.0.v200808251517
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.emf.ecore/osgi.bundle/2.4.1.v200808251517
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change/osgi.bundle/2.4.0.v200808251517
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit/osgi.bundle/2.4.1.v200808251517
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi/osgi.bundle/2.4.1.v200808251517
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.emf.edit/osgi.bundle/2.4.1.v200808251517
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.emf/osgi.bundle/1.1.202.v200809111955
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration/osgi.bundle/1.1.201.v200808071700
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks/osgi.bundle/1.1.200.v200805140020
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core/osgi.bundle/1.3.3.v200809102124
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.sse.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.302.v200808260045
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui/osgi.bundle/1.1.2.v200809120159
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.validation/osgi.bundle/1.2.2.v200809050219
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.wst.xml.core/osgi.bundle/1.1.305.v200809120354
```

What could this error mean, and how do I install the plugins. 
It's a new install of Eclipse and Vista 64bit. 
I used "http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.4" as the google plugin location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I got it.

I'd installed Eclipse Classic, and it didn't like it. 
Since then, I've uninstalled classic and installed "Eclipse Java EE" and the update worked.

Answer (score 24):

I had this problem today. I found this [helpful link](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/general/no-repository-found-containing-error-when-update-eclipse.html) which helped. Basically make sure all your sources' URLs end in a slash (/), and add them if they are missing.

I also went through all the sites and clicked the Test Connection button (I think that's what it's called) on each one to see if there was something wrong, and they all returned a successful result.

After that, suddenly I was able to install the features and plugins that had failed with the "No repository found" errors before.

Comment: I ran across that same link -- fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I have archive software sites witch be deleted and updater say about this.
Check **Windows -> Preferences -> Available Software Sites**. In this list should not be **archive sites witch deleted**. Then **restart eclipse**.

Comment: This answer does not make much sense, could you edit it for clarity?

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helped me with updating CDT! I'm on Luna but I still had a bunch of sites for Juno & Kepler that were screwing up my upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I just clean eclipse and run it worked.
in command prompt type eclipse -clean

This cleans the installation of eclipse and helps to run

Answer (score 2):

No necessarily to do all those import export and stuff.
Eclipse has a problem with itself. But it can be solved with a simple startup of

cmd> eclipse.exe -clean

it will take awhile to startup but eventually it worked for me. coz partially sometimes eclipse has problem unzipping files or so n partial files unzipped.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, what fixed it is to change the updating system that Eclipse used.  I am using Eclipse 3.5 and the default updating system is P2 (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started).  Try going into Prefereces->General->Capabilities-> check the box next to Classic Update.  This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your eclipse mirror was corrupt. Use another one.

Comment: I downloaded eclipse from a different mirror, but I still get the same error. I'm wondering if the issue is caused by the version of Java I have installed (6), or if it's something to do with running a 64bit OS. I continue to investigate.

Comment: It's not the download mirror, but the update site mirror - the one you use to install your plugins.

Comment: I'm using the default update site settings. Where can I find a list of update site mirrors?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'd assumed that i could use any version of Eclipse to do this, but it looks like I needed the Java EE version.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to update the Google plugin (clicking on the 'updates available' popup).

Reviewing my update sites, it turned out that the main **Google update site** (http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.5) **was missing**, although I doubt I had removed it.
Simply **re-adding** it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it doesn't work for me, until I removed all oracle's url from Available Software Sites as motioned in [eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/856519/), I still have some URLs without / at the end though.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error message while installing the Jboss Tools.

In the install dialog, I unchecked the option "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove an Oracle URL from update sites as well to get GWT plugin to update. I am using Eclipse Kepler with the following URL for GWT - https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, none of the solutions provided here worked for me (on Eclipse Luna). Had to update plugin via Marketplace.